# Loading data to a String Array from a String holding the array data in java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I actually have a String that contains the format of String array. And I want to load that string data into the array.

```
String data = "{"Sam" , "14","USA","7th"}";
```

and the String Array

```
String loaded_data[][];
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean String that has a format of String array? The first line provided is trying to assign a string array to a string type which isn't correct.

Comment: I have updated how it is

Comment: is this compiling i doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted.

Using `String.split()` splits the string into an string array with `,` regex.

```
    public void something() {
        String data = "{'Sam' , '14','USA','7th'}";

        data = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1); //Ignores curly brackets
        data = data.replaceAll("'", ""); //Removes apostrophes
        data = data.replaceAll(" ", ""); //Removes whitespace


        String[] loadedData = data.split(","); //Splits string -> string[]

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(loadedData));
    }
```

println:

```
[Sam, 14, USA, 7th]
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this to `String[][]` instead of `String[]`

Comment: what are you expecting the 2D array result to be? Instead of `[Sam, 14, USA, 7th]` it would be? `[[Sam,14],[USA,7th]]`?